# bokeh DataTable width

Tags: python, bokeh

Seems bokeh DataTable has a fixed whole table width?

When I set width of columns to be large, it will not work. The code below has 4 columns **width = 1000**, but it will only show 4 columns of much smaller width.

Also, although I can move the boundaries of each column in the output html in Chrome, I can't move the right end of the table in html -- The whole table width seems to be fixed.

Is there a way to have tables of large width?

```
import bokeh.models.widgets as bmw

source = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource(df)
numformatter = bmw.NumberFormatter()
numformatter.format = '0.00'
columns = [TableColumn(field=c, title=c, width = 1000, formatter=numformatter) for c in df]

table = bmw.DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, height = 1000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found out that `DataTable` has an attribute `width` (which is not documented). So

`table = bmw.DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, height = 1000, width = 4000)`

will work